# Unable to get the network's broadcast address with Python's Ipaddress module

Tags: python, network-programming

This is my code to get the broadcast address of my network:

```
def get_broadcast_address():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
    ip_addr = ipaddress.IPv4Network(s.getsockname()[0])
    ip_address = ipaddress.IPv4Network(s.getsockname()[0] + "/" + str(ip_addr.netmask))
    return ip_address.broadcast_address
```

It first gets the local IP and then the subnet mask. I know I can do a binary calculation to obtain the broadcast address, but I am wondering why the above function does not work.

This outputs `IPv4Address('192.168.1.47')`. I expect it to output 192.168.1.255. Why does this happen?

Comment: did you check your mask ? I get `32` but it seems you expect `24`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Address `IP` can be used with different `masks` - all depend on user/admin decision and settings in your system - and you can't expect that it will automatically use `24` for your address.

Socket gives `IP` but it doesn't give `mask`.

If you not set mask in `IPv4Network` (or other command) then it will use `32` which later gives you `192.168.1.47` instead of expected `192.168.1.255`

If you set manually `24` with your `IP` to create `Interface` then you can get expected `network` and expected `broadcast`.

```
import socket
import ipaddress

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))

socket_ip = s.getsockname()[0]
socket_ip = '192.168.1.47'
print('socket_ip   :', socket_ip)

network = ipaddress.IPv4Network(socket_ip)
print('network     :', network)
print('network mask:', network.netmask)

print('---')
mask = str(network.netmask)
print('mask:', mask)
ip_address = ipaddress.IPv4Interface(socket_ip + "/" + mask)
print('ip_address:', ip_address)
print('network   :', ip_address.network)
print('broadcast :', ip_address.network.broadcast_address)

print('---')
mask = '24'
print('mask:', mask)
ip_address = ipaddress.IPv4Interface(socket_ip + "/" + mask)
print('ip_address:', ip_address)
print('network   :', ip_address.network)
print('broadcast :', ip_address.network.broadcast_address)
```

Result

```
socket_ip   : 192.168.1.47
network     : 192.168.1.47/32
network mask: 255.255.255.255
---
mask: 255.255.255.255
ip_address: 192.168.1.47/32
network   : 192.168.1.47/32
broadcast : 192.168.1.47
---
mask: 24
ip_address: 192.168.1.47/24
network   : 192.168.1.0/24
broadcast : 192.168.1.255
```

---

To get correct mask you would have to ask system for this. Maybe with `psutil` or using `subprocess` with system command `ipconfig` (Windows) or `ifconfig` (Linux)

But if you have installed `psutil` then you don't need previous method

```
import psutil

for interface, data in psutil.net_if_addrs().items(): 
    addr = data[0]
    print('interface:', interface)
    print('address  :', addr.address)
    print('netmask  :', addr.netmask)
    print('broadcast:', addr.broadcast)
    print('---')
```

Result (for my Linux)

```
interface: lo
address  : 127.0.0.1
netmask  : 255.0.0.0
broadcast: None
---
interface: wlp5s0
address  : 192.168.1.31
netmask  : 255.255.255.0
broadcast: 192.168.1.255
---
interface: docker0
address  : 172.17.0.1
netmask  : 255.255.0.0
broadcast: 172.17.255.255
---
interface: enp3s0
address  : 00:26:2d:84:78:64
netmask  : None
broadcast: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Thanks. I got confused with the net mask.